# Fetch between records for alphanumeric column using numeric range in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

The alphanumeric ***record_no***  column contains multiple records like **'A123-2', 'B345-1', 'C786-1', '0000B11-1'**.

Now I wanted to fetch the records with the range by using something similar to

```
select * from table where column between '122' and '786'
```

and all the records should be display (ex. **'A123-2', 'B345-1', 'C786-1', '0000B11-1'**).

If I try complete ***record_no*** like **'A123-1'** to **'A786-1'** I am getting the result only for records starting with letter **A**.

Someone can please help me with fetching the records with the number range and displaying all the associated alphanumeric records?

Comment: To which number is `'0000B11-1'` supposed to map?

Comment: '0000B11-1' is an individual record itself no need to map. Hardly we can rename to 'B000011-1' if possible with a query as we may have multiple records with the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to match agains the first series of digits in the string.

If so, you can do:

```
where substring(col from '\d+')::int between 123 and 786
```

Comment: Query seems to be close but its giving me ERROR:  value "7852469321" is out of range for type integer
SQL state: 22003

Comment: @Raj: this was not showing in your sample data, where each string has just a few digits. Use `bigint` instead of `int`.

Comment: Wow its working perfect :). Yes @GMB, You are correct I could have mention more digit numbers in sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You want to predicate on the value between the letter and the hyphen? Probably you want to compare numerically, so worth a cast too. Something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE ( SUBSTRING(record_no, 1,  STRPOS(record_no, '-') - 1))::int 
BETWEEN 123 AND 786;
```

Comment: Great answer but I got ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "0000B11" SQL state: 22P02. I have updated the question by your answer.